# Loading text from a file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have created a function to get text from a file using an url. The function uses `$.get()` of jQuery to fetch the file. The function works fine but the problem here is `$.get()` is asynchronous so the order of the output is not predictable i tried changing it to synchronous but it freezes the page completely i have tried waiting for it to respond thinking i would take time but it didn't work.

Here's my code.

```
var File = (function () {
  return {
    GetTextFromFile:function(filePath) {
      console.log ("Start")

      $.get({
        url:filePath,
        async:true
      }, function (data) {
        console.log(data)
      });
      
      console.log ("End")
    }
  }
})();
```

This function outputs

```
Start
End
'Content_of_the_file'
```

This creates of problem because i cannot `return` the content of the file since it's not loaded yet because of the asynchronous get function. So is there any way to tell the function to wait till the `$.get()` has returned the content of the file.

Comment: Well you could have a stack to push whenever a new data is fetched thus order will be there with asynchronous

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: The async and await method worked for my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `async await` we can make asynchronous to work in sync mode.

```js
var File = (function () {
  return {
    GetTextFromFile: async function(filePath) {
      console.log ("Start")

      data = await $.get({
        url:filePath,
        async:true
      }, function (data) {
        return data
      });

      console.log(data)

      console.log ("End")
      return data
      
      
    }
  }
})();

await File.GetTextFromFile()
```